# AS3/Air app live and in app purchases no longer work

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have just had an app go live in the app store however when I test the in app purchases none of them work. I am using Distriqts ANE and everything works perfectly when in debug mode.

I have found posts that suggest they will start working after x amount of hours but this seems a bit crazy. Why would Apple not release the in app purchases at the same time as the app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are all your products available and approved for release in iTunesConnect? Are you getting any errors? Which stage of the purchase flow is it failing?

Comment: Yep, all products have been approved by Apple. Pretty much first process is failing. I can't even get to the purchase confirmation stage. All tests worked in debug mode and even when I reinstall the app as debug they work again.

Comment: Can you double check all your product ids are correct. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, all in app purchases started working about 30 hours after app was released so all good.

Comment: No problems! Have actually had a couple of reports of this happening so I've actually added it to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who comes across this problem, the answer is simply to wait. The AppStore takes a while to respond successfully even if your product has passed review.

See the last note in distriqt's documentation:

http://distriqt.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/254105-inappbilling

> If when you move your application to release you find the products are
>   not being able to be purchased you should firstly double check all
>   your products in iTunes Connect and then just simply wait.
>
> Unfortunately Apple may take up to several days to move your products
>   into production so we suggest you have all appropriate fall backs
>   showing in your application.